# Resize table background image without losing aspect ratio and make it responsive

Tags: html, image, css

I have tried several things but out of luck. I have an image containing text that needs to be set as the div or table's background image. I tried using background-size: cover, but when I do that, the image and the text inside it gets distorted. How can I set the background image without any distortion and also maintain the aspect ratio when resizing? A faster response would be helpful as I am frustrated after trying several things without any success.

Original image:https://dummyimage.com/1024x250/000000/fff.jpg&text=Coming+soon

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="150" style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/1024x250/000000/fff.jpg&text=Coming+soon); width: 100%; height: 100%; border:none; margin:0px; background-size: cover;">
<tr > 
<td width="80%" >
Test
</td>
<td width="20%" > 
Test
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the fiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/d95hd1dL/5/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="150">
 <tr > 
  <td width="80%" >
  Test
   </td>
    <td width="20%" > 
    Test
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
  background: #000 url(https://dummyimage.com/1024x250/000000/fff.jpg&text=Coming+soon);
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d95hd1dL/6/

Comment: Nice.. But can we make this work with the cellpadding reduced like cellpadding="30"? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try background-size:100% auto; insted of  background-size: cover;

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="150" style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/1024x250/000000/fff.jpg&text=Coming+soon); border:none; background-size:100% auto; margin:0px; ">
 <tr > 
  <td width="80%" >
  Test
   </td>
    <td width="20%" > 
    Test
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried setting it to 100% auto but the image doesn't resize correctly if I do that. In my case, I needed the background-position attribute.